# When I simulate from a multivariate distribution, do I need all the non-interesting terms?

Tags: probability, simulation

I would like to simulate from a multivariate distribution with mean vector $\mu$ and variance matrix $V$.

I am only interested in $\mu[1], ...., \mu[k]$ and their simulated values.

Does it make a difference if I draw from $N(\mu, V)$, and then extract the first $k$ values, or first extract the first $k$ values from $\mu$ and the first $k \times k$ submatrix of $V$, and then perform simulation from this multivariate normal?

I am not good enough at probability theory to know if it makes a difference.

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean. Are you simulating draws from multivariate normal distribution, or do you have some kind of model and you simulate parameters of multivariate normal distribution? What exactly do you simulate and how? Please describe the exact procedure.

Comment: @Tim OP should correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought it's fairly clear that they want to know if there's a difference between sampling $(X_1, \dots, X_p)$ and keeping only $(X_1, \dots, X_k)$ from $\mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$ versus directly sampling $(X_1, \dots, X_k)$ from $\mathcal N(\mu^*, \Sigma^*)$ where $\mu^*$ and $\Sigma^*$ are the natural restrictions

Answer (score 2):

In the first line of your question you don't specify that you mean the multivariate *normal* distribution, but based on the rest of the question I'm going to assume that.

You have a $p$-dimensional random vector $X$ that has a multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mu, \Sigma)$, but you only care about the first $k$ elements of this vector. You are considering two procedures:

1. generate full draws of $X$ and keep only the first $k$ elements
2. draw directly from the $k$-dimensional marginal multivariate normal distribution with parameters given by restricting $\mu$ to the first $k$ elements and $\Sigma$ to the upper $k \times k$ block.

It turns out these two things are equivalent, and both generate samples from the $k$-dimensional marginal distribution of $(X_1, \dots, X_k)$.

This is because it is a standard result (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions) rather terse paragraph in Wikipedia, for example) that if $$\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_p  \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mu_p\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} \dots \Sigma_{1p} \\ \vdots \\ \Sigma_{p1} \dots \Sigma_{pp}\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_k  \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal N\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mu_k\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} \dots \Sigma_{1k} \\ \vdots \\ \Sigma_{k1} \dots \Sigma_{kk}\end{bmatrix}\right).
$$
This means you can do exactly what you propose and just sample using the first $k$ elements of $\mu$ and the corresponding elements of $\Sigma$.